# PHP DATE Format corrupted, how can I fix it?

Tags: php, cakephp

I adjusted my html to be right to left and the database also to read right to left languages ex. Arabic, but the date shows in a corrupted format in the database browsing from PHP my admin, and also when retrieved in the browser it also is received in the same corrupted format, which is : 2002-09-15 and its supposed to be 02-09-2015, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the only logical thing would be take it apart and put it back together again with regex:

```
$date = "2002-09-15";
$newd = preg_replace( '/(\d{2})(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', '\2-\3-\1\4', $date);
echo $newd;
```

**Result**:

```
02-09-2015
```

I would normally tell you to use `date_format`, although I don't think it will work in this situation because of the year being mucked like it is.

Comment: CakePHP ships with tools that can handle date/time formatting: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html**

Comment: @ndm: Right, although the first two digits of the year in this case are concatenated with either the month or the day, so exactly how is it supposed to handle that?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that... it would be better then to fix this in the database, and wherever the source of the problem is. I could imagine that the date is being wrongly declared and saved in DD-MM-YY format somewhere, which will be interpreted as YY-MM-DD by the DBMS

Comment: when i use the preg_replace that you suggested up there, now it writes on the database 0000-00-00, now im getting frustrated :( @l'L'l